# Perlin Noise for 1D?

Tags: c#, algorithm, perlin-noise

Try as hard as I can, I cannot find any real tutorials on Perlin\Samplex Noise in 1D.

I've searched all around the internet but just cannot find anything. Any sites I do come across mentioning 1D perlin noise are usually very unclear or just shows the code

Comment: Did the code you found not work for you? There appear to be several code samples online that apply to your question ([one of which](http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/perlin-noise-in-c/)). Provided code is available and you're looking for code, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Its a combination of all the code out there being relatively hard to follow, and if there is code there is hardly any explanation on it.

Comment: You're asking about a complicated algorithm. Of course any code that implements it will be hard to follow. Do you understand what the code *should* do? If you did then the code on the net would likely be less hard to follow.

Comment: I can kind of understand the flow of the algorithm a little bit, it's just the lack of documentation of some people that make me confused. take for instance this function from one of the examples: float fade(in float t) {
 return t*t*t*(t*(t*6.0-15.0)+10.0);
}.... No header, no explanation on what this function is supposed to acheive, what is t? what is 6.0? It's just little things like this that throw me off from reading people's code. Copying code to me is what I'm forced to do, understand that code is a different issue altogether

Answer (score 27):

Late to the party, but it is proven, that a function like below is never periodic.

```
sin (2 * x) + sin(pi * x)
```

[image: Curve demonstrating sin (2 * x) + sin(pi * x)]

You can adopt the function in general, e.g. changing the 2 to 3, squashing the graph in y direction, **scaling** the x-frequency/periods of the individual sine's, you can also **move** the individual period by x. Many things, I've made a playground in the link below at geogebra, so you can play around with configurations, see what looks best, etc. The green graph would be the result, the purple graph is if you want the entire function to grow to a theoretical infinity, the orange doted graph is a constant configuration of the function that we see red above, and the yellow lined graph is everything without the scalings. Enjoy!

Hint: You don't need two irrational numbers for a non-periodic function. You could also use the square root of two for example.

https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/yzgxvd8q

[image: What you Can Configure using the graph.]

Comment: Late to the party but the square root of two *is* irrational. The criterion for aperiodicity is that the ratio of the frequencies should be irrational.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question but here is one of the clearest explanations about the interpolation between fixed points that makes up 1d Perlin noise http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf

One of the most important things to know, useful in all programming is the interpolation function...

http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/

once you have random points with smoothstep interpolation, you have a kind of smooth 1d noise function.

see smoothstep on wiki. a lot of on the topic via google. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep

apparently the hyperlink is unstable, here it is again:

Simplex noise demystified

Ken Perlin presented “simplex noise”, a replacement for his classic noise algorithm.
Classic “Perlin noise” won him an academy award and has become an ubiquitous procedural
primitive for computer graphics over the years, but in hindsight it has quite a few limitations.
Ken Perlin himself designed simplex noise specifically to overcome those limitations, and he
spent a lot of good thinking on it. Therefore, it is a better idea than his original algorithm.

A few
of the more prominent advantages are:

• Simplex noise has a lower computational complexity and requires fewer multiplications.

• Simplex noise scales to higher dimensions (4D, 5D and up) with much less computational cost, the complexity is for dimensions instead of the of classic Noise.

• Simplex noise has no noticeable directional artifacts.

• Simplex noise has a well-defined and continuous gradient everywhere that can be computed
quite cheaply.

• Simplex noise is easy to implement in hardware.

Sadly, even now in early 2005 very few people seem to understand simplex noise, and almost
nobody uses it, which is why I wrote this. I will try to explain the algorithm a little more thoroughly
than Ken Perlin had time to do in his course notes from Siggraph 2001 and 2002, and
hopefully make it clear that it is not as difficult to grasp as it first seems.
From what I’ve learned, what confuses people the most is the impenetrable nature of Ken Perlin’s
reference implementation in Java. He presents very compact and uncommented code to
demonstrate the principle, but that code is clearly not meant to be read as a tutorial. After a few
attempts I gave up on the code and read his paper instead, which was a lot more clear.

Not crystal
clear, though, as he presents the algorithm mostly in words and code snippets. I would have
appreciated some graphs and figures and a few helpful equations, and that’s what I try to provide
here, to make it easier for others to understand the greatness and beauty of simplex noise. I will
also explain things in one and two dimensions first to make things easier to explain with graphs
and images, and then move on to three and four dimensions.
Classic noise
In order to explain simplex noise, it is helpful to have a good understanding of classic Perlin
noise. I have seen quite a few bad and misinformed explanations in this area, so to make sure
that you have the necessary groundwork done, I will present classic Perlin noise first.

Perlin noise is a so-called gradient noise, which means that you set a pseudo-random gradient
at regularly spaced points in space, and interpolate a smooth function between those points. To
generate Perlin noise in one dimension, you associate a pseudo-random gradient (or slope) for
the noise function with each integer coordinate, and set the function value at each integer coordinate
to zero.

For a given point somewhere between two integer points, the value is interpolated between
two values, namely the values that would have been the result if the closest linear slopes from
the left and from the right had been extrapolated to the point in question. This interpolation is a smoothstep algo.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: It wasn't dead i clicked on it the same day as you checked it. it's alive.

Comment: No need to use simplex noise in 1d. Ordinary algorithm would be cheaper. Also you can adapt improved perlin noise version for achieving even better performance.

Comment: You never completed your answer :|

Comment: The answer is actually complete.  The entire answer is just the beginning text from the PDF in the first link.

Comment: The link is dead again, here's a backup (copy & paste the whole thing into your address bar): https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf